# spring xml based configuration from java based configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redis, spring-3

I am doing sample chat application using spring mvc and redis server by following steps from
http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/16/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-chat-sample/

the example given there is by spring java based configurations. I want to do with xml based configurations. But it is not working for me.

I am getting the issues by converting following configuration class

```
package org.springframework.samples.async.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.StringRedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.listener.PatternTopic;
import org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.samples.async.chat.ChatController;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:redis.properties")
public class RootConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Autowired
    ChatController chatController;

    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory cf = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        cf.setHostName(this.env.getProperty("redis.host"));
        cf.setPort(this.env.getProperty("redis.port", int.class));
        cf.setPassword(this.env.getProperty("redis.password"));
        return cf;
    }

    @Bean
    public StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate() {
        return new StringRedisTemplate(redisConnectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisMessageListenerContainer redisMessageListenerContainer() {
        RedisMessageListenerContainer mlc = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        mlc.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        mlc.addMessageListener(this.chatController , new PatternTopic("chat"));
        return mlc;
    }

}
```

The following is the Xml based configuration i am trying to use instead of above java based configuration.

```
<bean id="redisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
        p:host-name="localhost" p:port="9994" p:password=""/>
<bean id="messageListener" class="org.springframework.data.redis.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.samples.async.chat.ChatController"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="redisMessageListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="redisConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="messageListeners">s          
      <map>
        <entry key-ref="messageListener">
            <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.listener.PatternTopic">
               <constructor-arg value="chat"/>
            </bean>
        </entry>
      </map>
    </property>
 </bean>
```

**The exception i am getting is**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageListener' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/mvc-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.samples.async.chat.ChatController#74b70648' of type [org.springframework.samples.async.chat.ChatController] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.samples.async.chat.ChatController] for bean with name 'org.springframework.samples.async.chat.ChatController#74b70648' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/mvc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.samples.async.chat.ChatController
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:629)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1049)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:600)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:519)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:460)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at jav
```

a.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

**ChatController.java**

```
package org.springframework.samples.async.chat;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.Message;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.MessageListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/mvc/chat")
public class ChatController implements MessageListener {

    private final Map<DeferredResult<List<String>>, Integer> chatRequests =
            new ConcurrentHashMap<DeferredResult<List<String>>, Integer>();

    private final ChatRepository chatRepository;


    @Autowired
    public ChatController(ChatRepository chatRepository) {
        this.chatRepository = chatRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public DeferredResult<List<String>> getMessages(@RequestParam int messageIndex) {

        final DeferredResult<List<String>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<List<String>>(null, Collections.emptyList());
        this.chatRequests.put(deferredResult, messageIndex);

        deferredResult.onCompletion(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                chatRequests.remove(deferredResult);
            }
        });

        List<String> messages = this.chatRepository.getMessages(messageIndex);
        if (!messages.isEmpty()) {
            deferredResult.setResult(messages);
        }

        return deferredResult;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void postMessage(@RequestParam String message) {
        this.chatRepository.addMessage(message);
    }

    // Redis MessageListener contract

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] pattern) {
        for (Entry<DeferredResult<List<String>>, Integer> entry : this.chatRequests.entrySet()) {
            List<String> messages = this.chatRepository.getMessages(entry.getValue());
            entry.getKey().setResult(messages);
        }
    }
```

}

**The complete mvc-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
<mvc:annotation-driven>
 <mvc:async-support default-timeout="30000" />
</mvc:annotation-driven>
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="chat"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="resources"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.samples.async.chat" />
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
        <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="viewNames" value="*.html"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="stringRedisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.StringRedisTemplate"
    p:connection-factory-ref="redisConnectionFactory"/>

<bean id="redisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
        p:host-name="localhost" p:port="9994" p:password=""/>
<bean id="messageListener" class="org.springframework.data.redis.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.samples.async.chat.ChatController"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="redisMessageListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="redisConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="messageListeners">
      <!-- map of listeners and their associated topics (channels or/and patterns) -->
      <map>
        <entry key-ref="messageListener">
            <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.listener.PatternTopic">
               <constructor-arg value="chat"/>
            </bean>
        </entry>
      </map>
    </property>
 </bean>


</beans>
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are trying to do some sort of autowire by class thing in your xml with this portion (I am assuming):

```
<bean id="messageListener" class="org.springframework.data.redis.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.samples.async.chat.ChatController"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

But that is not how the xml configuration works.  What the xml is doing here is trying to create a new instance of the `ChatController` and use it as a constructor argument to the `MessageListenerAdapter`.  Obviously this doesn't work because your `ChatController` has no 0 arg constructors.  What you want to do instead is reference your existing `ChatController` (which is marked as an `@Controller` and will therefore be automatically picked up by your `component-scan`) in the constructor argument.  Something like this:

```
<bean id="messageListener" class="org.springframework.data.redis.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="chatController"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

The bean being referenced by 'chatController' is your component-scanned `ChatController` (it is the default bean name when none is provided via the stereotype annotations or the `@Qualifier` annotation).

Comment: thanks for the quick response.Still some issues.Can you please tell me how exactly the following code can be converted to xml                                                               @Bean
public RedisMessageListenerContainer redisMessageListenerContainer() {
  RedisMessageListenerContainer mlc = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
  mlc.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
  mlc.addMessageListener(this.chatController , new PatternTopic("chat"));
  return mlc; }

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to ask these specific parts or you should ask a new question.  Otherwise it is not likely that anyone else will see this.